# Date problem with sql - displaying only one row

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

i've go a table with employee_id, school_end(date), school_name
and some employeers have a several school names with dates.

i want to see in query only the latest school and date for one employee_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to see in query only the latest school and date for one employee_id

One cross-database solution to this top-1-per-group question is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.school_end = (
    select max(t1.school_end) from mytable t1 where t1.employee_id = t.employee_id
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(employee_id, school_end)`.

Depending on your database, more efficient options might be available (for example, Postgres has the `distinct on` syntax).

Comment: hi, thanks for that - it working correctly. One more problem, i have some records in school._end with  no date (null) - i cant seen them in results of query...